# Inserting a value in particular cell of DB2 blu table

Tags: sql, db2

I want to insert a value in a column "column_1" of table "table_1" with a condition where column "column_2" has a particular value and column "column_3" value is not like some value.
"column_2" and "column_3" are both in the same table "table_1".

I tried the following query but I am not getting require result.

`INSERT INTO Table_1 (Column_1) VALUES ('Distribution') where column_2 = 'ABC' and column_3 not like '%123%'`

Can anyone help me in writing proper query for this requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `update`:

```
update table_1
    set column_1 = 'Distribution'
    where column_2 = 'ABC' and column_3 not like '%123%';
```

`insert` adds new rows to the table.  `update` changes values in columns in existing rows.